# Можно ли программно эмулировать нажатие глобальных клавиш?

Tags: c++, qt, hotkeys

Нужно программно эмулировать нажатие сочетание горячих клавиш. Обработка в другом приложении. Если это возможно, то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если окна нет, кто принимает события нажатия горячих клавиш? Окна может и не видно, но он есть и у него есть функция окна. Это для `Windows`. Посмотрите утилитой аналогичной `spy++`, есть ли у него окна. Если да, то пользуйтесь [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx) и [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx).
Если приложение не имеет окон и реагирует на горячие клавиши, скорее всего оно установило [хук](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

получаешь дескриптор окна другого приложения и посылаеш ему сообшения KeyPreset с кодами клавишь

Comment: Окна может и не быть.